# How to automatically eliminate dimensions in WEKA

Tags: weka, data-mining, feature-selection

I have applied feature selection algorithm on some high dimensional dataset in WEKA, which gives rank wise list of features based on symetric uncertainty. Now i want to eliminate those features which are having 0 uncertainty value. But there is around 10,000 features in dataset, so it is not possible to eliminate required features manually.  Is there any method to automatically eliminate dimensions in WEKA?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is perform classification on the reduced dataset, use [AttributeSelectedClassifier](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/meta/AttributeSelectedClassifier.html). This 'wraps' the classifier in the attribute selection algorithm.

As well as the convenience advantage, this means that the attribute selection is done *inside* the cross-validation process, so that you don't get an overoptimistic estimate of your classifier's performance - if you did the attribute selection first and then built and cross-validated the classifier on the reduced dataset, you'd be 'cheating' by leaking some knowledge about the validation dataset into the training procedure.